# Is WSDL still used?

Tags: rest, web-services, cloud-computing, soap

As today most of the development is towards the lightweight service and RESTful architecture, is WSDL still needed to describe these services? In today's world -- where cloud computing, mobile computing, and Internet of Things are dominating -- is WSDL and UDDI still used by industry or practitioners?

Comment: Never been aware of it as being relevant to RESTful. Is there a more specific question behind this question?

Comment: Yes, we using it this year too. WSDLs are generated by tools from function prototypes and shouldn't add to hustle. BUT. Keep in mind that some platforms may have problems with incompatible standards of WSDL

Comment: "Needed" and "is used" are different things. Please clarify.

Comment: @Gherman “incompatible standards”??   Now there’s an oxymoron....  I’d stay away.

Comment: WSDL was never needed to describe services.  It's more of a *discovery* mechanism.  If you already know a service's schema, you don't need WSDL to successfully communicate with it.

Comment: UDDI is dead (or was never alive) as far I know.

Answer (score 4):

A wsdl is just a contract saying this is how you can call this service. Of course you also have (Json) webapi endpoints that don't have a formal description these days (and you could with odata you get a wsdl-ish metadata description)
However soap services with a wsdl still have it's place. A new trend doesn't mean there isn't a use case for the old way.And don't forget many companies still have legacy systems.

So yes it's still being used.